# BufferedReader readLine and OutputStreamWriter .write

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, readline

I have 2 programs: a client and a server.

The server creates a ServerSocket and the client connects using:

```
address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
conn = new Socket(address, port);
```

this works, but here is the problem: `void mousePressed() {` gets called once the mouse is clicked, executing this: (client side)

```
void mousePressed() {
  try {
    BufferedOutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "US-ASCII");
    osw.write("123");
        osw.flush();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

the server should receive the input using:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream())));
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
    result.append(line);
}
reader.close();
println(result.toString());
```

The server only receives the input after the socket has been closed with: `conn.close();` on the client side or quitting the client. As i want to be able to click the mouse multiple times, i can't close the socket.

What can i do to send input without closing the socket?

Edit: connection code:

Server:

```
 // init
    ServerSocket socket1;
    int main_port = 5204;
    // in main
    try {
          socket1 = new ServerSocket(main_port);
          Socket conn = socket1.accept();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Client:

```
// init
    String host = "localhost";
    int port = 5204;
    Socket conn;
    InetAddress address;
    // in main
    try {
          address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
          conn = new Socket(address, port);
         } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Also, **never** eat the exceptions.`catch (Exception e) { }` does nothing!

Comment: The hint is in the name `readLine()`.  It reads a line of text and you're not sending one.  Try sending a newline i.e. `\n`

Comment: @ShashankKadne worse it throws away errors you are likely to need to know esp if your software doesn't work perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution (based on other answers and comments):

1) Changing `osw.write("123");` to `osw.write("123\n");` in the client.

2) Replacing

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new
BufferedInputStream(thread_cnn.getInputStream())));        
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
    result.append(line);
}
println(result);
reader.close();
```

with

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream())));        
String result = reader.readLine().toString();
println(result);
reader = null;
result = null;
```

on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing an incomplete line, and trying to read complete lines. Terminate the text you send with a line break so it can be read when it arrives.

Also, do not catch and ignore exceptions. If something goes wrong you will want to know about it.

```
  try {
    BufferedOutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "US-ASCII");
    osw.write("123\n");
    osw.flush();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: that makes the server go into the for loop once, but it still does not output `result.toString()` until the client closes the socket.

Comment: That's because the server has a loop that tries to read everything the client sends until the client closes the socket. Remove the loop if you don't want that to happen.